# VBA script to split text file

Tags: vba, text, mysqli, io, split

I'm trying to learn more about input-output scripting in VBA, can anyone assist with splitting a text in to separate files. The sample data I have is

```
REPORT ID: HR125
PAGE:     1
DATE: 20161122              LOCATION: 01

CUSTOMER ID: 000201 NAME: JOE
ACCOUNTING CODE: KS0012
SPENDING FY: 6000 
PREVIOUS YEAR SPENDING: 7500
CUSTOMER DATA

REPORT ID: HR125
PAGE:     2
DATE: 20161122              LOCATION: 01

ADDRESS: 1234 A STREET          STATE: KS
BONUS: 1000
CUSTOMER DATA


REPORT ID: HR125
PAGE:     1
DATE: 20161122              LOCATION: 01

CUSTOMER ID: 000505 NAME: JILL
ACCOUNTING CODE: KS0012
SPENDING FY: 8000 
PREVIOUS YEAR SPENDING: 5750
CUSTOMER DATA

REPORT ID: HR125
PAGE:     2
DATE: 20161122              LOCATION: 01

ADDRESS: 4321 B STREET          STATE: MO
BONUS: 1000
CUSTOMER DATA

REPORT ID: HR125
PAGE:     1
DATE: 20161122              LOCATION: 01

CUSTOMER ID: 000201 NAME: MIKE
ACCOUNTING CODE: KS5010
SPENDING FY: 5500 
PREVIOUS YEAR SPENDING: 5500
CUSTOMER DATA

REPORT ID: HR125
PAGE:     2
DATE: 20161122              LOCATION: 01

ADDRESS: 1234 C STREET          STATE: MO
BONUS: 1000
CUSTOMER DATA

REPORT ID: HR125
PAGE:     1
DATE: 20161122              LOCATION: 01

CUSTOMER ID: 000505 NAME: JAKE
ACCOUNTING CODE: KS5010
SPENDING FY: 4600 
PREVIOUS YEAR SPENDING: 5050
CUSTOMER DATA

REPORT ID: HR125
PAGE:     2
DATE: 20161122              LOCATION: 01

ADDRESS: 4321 D STREET          STATE: IA
BONUS: 1000
CUSTOMER DATA

REPORT ID: HR125
PAGE:     1
DATE: 20161122              LOCATION: 01

CUSTOMER ID: 000505 NAME: JOHN
ACCOUNTING CODE: KS5010
SPENDING FY: 5600 
PREVIOUS YEAR SPENDING: 5750
CUSTOMER DATA

REPORT ID: HR125
PAGE:     2
DATE: 20161122              LOCATION: 01

ADDRESS: 4321 D STREET          STATE: MO
BONUS: 1000
CUSTOMER DATA
```

I would like to split the file by the ACCOUNTING ID and name it also as such for each splitted file.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is not a code for me service nor is it a teach me to code site. It is a site where those with existing code that does not work can get help overcoming the problem. If you have code that is not working please post it in the original post with an explanation of the error. Without code and a explanation this will likely be down voted and closed.

Comment: Hint.  There is *literally* a VBA function named `Split()`.

Answer (score 0):

The script below should do what you want.  The only thing is, your data needs to be in a hierarchy format.  It's hard to tell if your data is setup correctly now.

```
Sub Copy_To_Workbooks()
'Note: This macro use the function LastRow
    Dim My_Range As Range
    Dim FieldNum As Long
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim foldername As String
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim CCount As Long
    Dim WSNew As Worksheet
    Dim ErrNum As Long

    'Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A1 is the top left cell of your filter range
    'and the header of the first column, D is the last column in the filter range.
    'You can also add the sheet name to the code like this :
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D" & LastRow(Worksheets("Sheet1")))
    'No need that the sheet is active then when you run the macro when you use this.
    Set My_Range = Range("A1:D" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
    My_Range.Parent.Select

    If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
       My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
               vbOKOnly, "Copy to new workbook"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'This example filters on the first column in the range(change the field if needed)
    'In this case the range starts in A so Field:=1 is column A, 2 = column B, ......
    FieldNum = 1

    'Turn off AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Set the file extension/format
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007-2013
        If ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat = 56 Then
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
        Else
            FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        End If
    End If

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    'Delete the sheet RDBLogSheet if it exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("RDBLogSheet").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Add worksheet to copy/Paste the unique list
    Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    ws2.Name = "RDBLogSheet"

    'Fill in the path\folder where you want the new folder with the files
    'you can use also this "C:\Users\Ron\test"
    MyPath = Application.DefaultFilePath

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'Create folder for the new files
    foldername = MyPath & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss") & "\"
    MkDir foldername

    With ws2
        'first we copy the Unique data from the filter field to ws2
        My_Range.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
                Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                CopyToRange:=.Range("A3"), Unique:=True

        'loop through the unique list in ws2 and filter/copy to a new sheet
        Lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cell In .Range("A4:A" & Lrow)

            'Filter the range
            My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, Criteria1:="=" & _
             Replace(Replace(Replace(cell.Value, "~", "~~"), "*", "~*"), "?", "~?")

            'Check if there are no more then 8192 areas(limit of areas)
            CCount = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                     .Areas(1).Cells.Count
            On Error GoTo 0
            If CCount = 0 Then
                MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas for the value : " & cell.Value _
                     & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data." _
                     & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
                       vbOKOnly, "Split in worksheets"
            Else
                'Add new workbook with one sheet
                Set WSNew = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

                'Copy/paste the visible data to the new workbook
                My_Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                With WSNew.Range("A1")
                    ' Paste:=8 will copy the columnwidth in Excel 2000 and higher
                    ' Remove this line if you use Excel 97
                    .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    .Select
                End With

                'Save the file in the new folder and close it
                On Error Resume Next
                WSNew.Parent.SaveAs foldername & _
                                    cell.Value & FileExtStr, FileFormatNum
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    ErrNum = ErrNum + 1

                    WSNew.Parent.SaveAs foldername & _
                     "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000") & FileExtStr, FileFormatNum

                    .Cells(cell.Row, "B").Formula = "=Hyperlink(""" & foldername & _
                      "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000") & FileExtStr & """)"

                    .Cells(cell.Row, "A").Interior.Color = vbRed
                Else
                    .Cells(cell.Row, "B").Formula = _
                    "=Hyperlink(""" & foldername & cell.Value & FileExtStr & """)"
                End If

                WSNew.Parent.Close False
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If

            'Show all the data in the range
            My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum

        Next cell
        .Cells(1, "A").Value = "Red cell: can't use the Unique name as file name"
        .Cells(1, "B").Value = "Created Files (Click on the link to open a file)"
        .Cells(3, "A").Value = "Unique Values"
        .Cells(3, "B").Value = "Full Path and File name"
        .Cells(3, "A").Font.Bold = True
        .Cells(3, "B").Font.Bold = True
        .Columns("A:B").AutoFit

    End With

    'Turn off AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    If ErrNum > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Rename every WorkSheet name that start with ""Error_"" manually" _
             & vbNewLine & "There are characters in the name that are not allowed" _
             & vbNewLine & "in a sheet name or the worksheet already exist."
    End If

    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    My_Range.Parent.Select
    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    ws2.Select
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub


Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```